# Disabled form tag not working Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I cannot figure out why this is happening.

I have a form like so..

```
<form class="invite-users__form" #addUserForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" max-length="15" [(ngModel)]="firstName" name="firstName" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" max-length="15" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="lastName" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="form-label" for="email">Email</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" email pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z.-]{2,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z]{2,}"
              required>
      </div>
      <p class="form-label">Select Role</p>
      <ul class="role-select__selection">
          <li class="role-select__role" (click)="roleSelect('role1')">role1</li>
          <li class="role-select__role" (click)="roleSelect('role2')">role2</li>
      </ul>
      <p class="form-label m--margin-top-10">Allow admin permissions</p>
      <div class="admin-permission__container">
          <button (click)="permissionSelect(true)" class="admin-permission__button button-true">YES</button>
          <button (click)="permissionSelect(false)" class="admin-permission__button button-false">NO</button>
      </div>
  </form>
```

and a button that controls the form like so..

```
<div class="m-login__form-action">
<button 
   [disabled]="!addUserForm.form.valid" 
   [ngClass]="{'invalid': (!addUserForm.form.valid)}" 
   (click)="addUser()" 
   class="account-step__button">
          <span class="register__button__text">SEND INVITE</span>
</button>
  </div>
```

now what I want to do is keep the form disabled until a user has selected a role and also selected whether or not they are an admin so I have done this...

```
<button 
   [disabled]="!addUserForm.form.valid && userRole === undefined && allowAdmin === undefined" 
   [ngClass]="{'invalid': (!addUserForm.form.valid && userRole === undefined && allowAdmin === undefined)}" 
   (click)="addUser()" 
   class="account-step__button">
          <span class="register__button__text">SEND INVITE</span>
</button>
  </div>
```

in my component I have set

```
userRole;
allowAdmin;
```

so they are undefined, now what happens is the from is valid but the `userRole` and `allowAdmin` are both undefined but the invalid class is removed and the button is undisabled?

I can't figure out what the issue is?

Comment: Probably just a typo in "allowAdin === undefined"

Comment: @AkshayRana hey sorry no the typo isnt in the project just mispelled it when rewriting it here

Comment: On the second template, '!' is missing on the line "addUserForm.form.valid". Just to confirm you have it in the code or not?
Also, you can print the values above the button to check the behavior like : 
Validation : {{addUserForm.form.valid}}, userRole  : {{userRole}}, allowAdmin : {{allowAdmin}}

Comment: Your form is invalid because you use required attribute on your input controls

Comment: @yurzui you clearly didnt read the question, what is happening is my form IS VALID when It shouldn't be. The input controls are supposed to be required

Comment: @AkshayRana I have done what you said and the from is showing valid but userRole and allowAdmin are still undefined.. so the button should be still disabled but it isnt

Comment: You added `!` to `addUserForm.form.valid` so it should work now https://ng-run.com/edit/6HM3LFciXDDiDUIdh188

Comment: @yurzui your code example shows my exact problem, the send invite button show not be active until they have selected userRole and allowAdmin

Comment: `[disabled]="!addUserForm.form.valid || userRole === undefined || allowAdmin === undefined"` If you want that everything should be valid Check it here https://ng-run.com/edit/6HM3LFciXDDiDUIdh188 Fill all the fields, check role and choose permission

Comment: @yurzui yes thankyou this works!